# How to write a pre-mount startup script for dracut?

Tags: storage, dracut

I want to create a script that suspends the system for 2 seconds before filesystem mount because of a firmware bug on my acer laptop specified on the [ArchLinux-Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Laptop/Acer#Aspire_3_A315-56_internal_storage_not_showing_up). That article tells me how to do it on `mkinitcpio` but not on `dracut`.

If someone can guide me through the process it would be much appreciated, I'm quite new to all of this.